# What should I need to do after a CPU/IGP change in Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: ubuntu, hardware, central-processing-unit, software

On the next week I'd like to change my cpu from an Intel G3930 to G4600.

What should I need to do and why? Can I change without reinstall anything? Linux can handle this automatic? Do I need for example update the initramfs? I use the IGP, mostly that's worries me.

**Intel Celeron G3930**

- 2 cores, 2 threads
- Intel HD Graphics 610

**Intel Pentium G4600**

- 2 cores, 4 threads
- Intel HD Graphics 630

Comment: What sort of server is this that's got a Celeron?? anyway all you've added is threading which the kernel will pick up automatically, so do nothing.

Comment: This is off topic for here, it would be better asked at Super User or the Unix SE.